# Positioning widgets within ListView

Tags: flutter

[image]This is what I want to do. **Form** is a *Column* with a few *TextField*-s that have to be in the middle of the screen. **Footer** is another *Column* with a single *Text* widget but positioned at the bottom of the screen. Both columns are in a *Stack*. It looks fine when **Form** is small but if its height is more than screen height (for example, when the keyboard is open) I cannot scroll to view the whole **Form** and **Footer** appears above everything.

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
    child: Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            // Form
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            // Footer
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

So I decided to put them in ListView instead of Stack. The scrolling problem is already fixed but now positioning is not correct - they are on the top. How to put Form into the center and Footer at the bottom?

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
    child: Center(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            // Form
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            // Footer
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: if you want your footer to be stuck at bottom all the time then try using `bottomNavigationBar` under `scaffold` widget

Comment: and I think try restructuring your widgets, and if it's doesn't help what you are looking for feel free to ping. a clear requirement would be helpful as right now it seems to be too much clutter

Comment: Yes, this is my first app and I'm not sure how exactly to structure my widgets. ```bottomNavigationBar``` puts the Footer exactly where I want but... I want to use a single background for the whole page (it's gradient). So Footer have to be with transparent background.

Comment: you can set a background color for every widget (scaffold and others too) if that's what you are looking for